# Apparent Race condition when deleting and recreating a elasticsearch index via the Java API

Tags: java, indexing, elasticsearch

I am getting a error - index already exists when creating a index I just deleted. Below is a simple test I created to replicate the behaviour:

```
        Client elasticSearchClient = elasticSearchLocalService.getClient();
        if (elasticSearchClient.admin().indices().exists(new IndicesExistsRequest(indexName)).get().isExists())
            elasticSearchClient.admin().indices().delete(new DeleteIndexRequest(indexName)).get();
        elasticSearchClient.admin().indices().exists(new IndicesExistsRequest(indexName)).get().isExists();//returns false
        elasticSearchClient.admin().indices().create(new CreateIndexRequest(indexName)).get();
```

Even though the second call to check if a index exists returns false I still get the error, I've tried to Refresh the index but I think that only affects data. 
I expected the .get on the delete to block until everything was finished.

Thanks !

Comment: Shouldn the 4th line be in a if?

Comment: Thats really only there for debug purposes, because according to the api the delete should block